# How to pass user data to

Tags: swift, alert

I'd like to pass data to the driveMeTo handler. How should I do that?
See code below:

```
    var alert = UIAlertController(title: annotation.title, message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Close", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel, handler:handleCancel))
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Y aller", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler:driveMeTo))
    self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)



func driveMeTo(alertView: UIAlertAction!)
{
  println "Where I want the data passed"
}
```

Comment: Third line, driveMeTo @Bryan Chen

Comment: which is it? show how do you create it

Comment: The handler itself is of no use. I added it though. @Bryan Chen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use closure

```
var foo = "test"
alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Y aller",
    style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, 
    handler:{(action : UIAlertAction!) -> Void in 
        println(foo) // you can refer to variable in outer scope
    }))
```